# zookeeper on ec2 cannot run

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper

Everyone, 
I am recently setting up zookeeper on ec2
I have followed the manual of ec2, but it still shows up the error:

```
root@ip-172-31-15-65:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin# ./zkServer.sh status
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

But the instance is running in the background.
Then when I use the ./zkCli.sh –server server-ip:2181 command, it shows below

```
root@ip-172-31-15-68:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin# ./zkCli.sh -server ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
Connecting to ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
2013-08-31 06:53:05,568 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
2013-08-31 06:53:05,579 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:host.name=ip-172-31-15-68.us-west-2.compute.internal
2013-08-31 06:53:05,580 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_25
2013-08-31 06:53:05,580 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2013-08-31 06:53:05,581 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
2013-08-31 06:53:05,582 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../build/classes:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../lib/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib
2013-08-31 06:53:05,583 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2013-08-31 06:53:05,584 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2013-08-31 06:53:05,584 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2013-08-31 06:53:05,585 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-08-31 06:53:05,586 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2013-08-31 06:53:05,586 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-40-virtual
2013-08-31 06:53:05,587 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.name=root
2013-08-31 06:53:05,588 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.home=/root
2013-08-31 06:53:05,588 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.dir=/home/yjiang/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin
2013-08-31 06:53:05,592 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@3b8a9e64
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
2013-08-31 06:53:05,695 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@966] - Opening socket connection to server ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/54.213.208.202:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
JLine support is enabled
[zk: ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181(CONNECTING) 0] 2013-08-31 06:53:35,756 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1083] - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 30097ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2013-08-31 06:53:36,860 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@966] - Opening socket connection to server ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/54.213.208.202:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

It seems take forever to connect.

I did setup everything according to docs, I don’t know what I did wrong.
The following is my conf file, and the myid is in the dataDir folder

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
dataDir=/home/yjiang/zookeeper/data/zk1
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2888:3888
#server.3=ec2-54-213-208-225.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2888:3888
#server.4=ip-172-31-15-66.us-west-2.compute.internal:3888
#server.5=ip-172-31-26-18.us-west-2.compute.internal:3888
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

FYI I have added the port 2181, 2888 and 3888 to my firewalls in all machines. I even disabled the firewall in all machines, it still doesn’t work. But there is never any problem in my local with same configuration approach.
Please help me
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find the way out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have to do with AWS interval vs. external addresses.  Each EC2 instance has an address to use from within AWS (the private address) and an address to use outside of AWS.  Your configure file shows server2 using ec2-54-213-208-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com which is definitely an external address.  If all of your servers and in AWS make sure they all are using private addresses.

Comment: AWS public hostnames resolve to their private IP from inside the same region. This is always the preferred way, as using the public IP explicitly is slower and traffic will be billed.